# How can I get data from function into dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape property data from a real estate listing website. I found all relevant data inside the <script> tag:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    app.start({
        el: $('body'),
        property: {
            code: 'A7589',
            subtype: 'Duplex',
            type: 'Appartement',
            price: 285000.00,
            mainImg: 'https://files.test.com/IMG_7674.jpeg',
            images: [{"z-detail":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/n5H1aP91sXITLfFDWsVN_Er6mOg=\/500x380\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","z-detail-large":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/z76D59FEYt1QYtSBlUX7867FwlE=\/fit-in\/1200x1200\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","z-result":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/TgubrXW2Mv22UWOe4d67vUWVAwA=\/828x618\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","z-result-310":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/7K4ZKsGVKBTrbrel3FEUehkvcdA=\/310x231\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","tickers":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/hZrwfjBmnbp5KxTWY_SnXp6jsqM=\/168x136\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg"}],
            proj_id: 0,
            popularity: 1,
            province: "Testprovince",
                        },
        sellerType: 'Seller',
        page: 'property',
        energyData: null,
        loanSimulation: {"loan15":1666.8976970020065,"loan20":1329.403635377926,"loan25":1129.2767807421394,"registration":12062.61,"loanCosts":5531.3992},
        plusToken: '',
    });

    app.TrackingCodeHandler.call("criteo", function() {
        if (typeof window.criteo_q === 'undefined') {
            window.criteo_q = [];
        }
        window.criteo_q.push(
            {event: "viewItem", item: "K20OX"}
        );
    });
});
    $(function () {
        app.TrackingCodeHandler.call("DoubleclickFloodlight");
        app.TrackingCodeHandler.call("Hotjar");
        app.TrackingCodeHandler.call("CxenseAndEnreach");

    });
```

Ideally I would be able to extract the property data to a dictionary so I have this as a result:

```
property= {
'code': 'A7589',
'subtype': 'Duplex',
'type': 'Appartement',
'price': 285000.00,
'mainImg': 'https://files.test.com/IMG_7674.jpeg',
'images': [{"z-detail":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/n5H1aP91sXITLfFDWsVN_Er6mOg=\/500x380\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","z-detail-large":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/z76D59FEYt1QYtSBlUX7867FwlE=\/fit-in\/1200x1200\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","z-result":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/TgubrXW2Mv22UWOe4d67vUWVAwA=\/828x618\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","z-result-310":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/7K4ZKsGVKBTrbrel3FEUehkvcdA=\/310x231\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","tickers":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/hZrwfjBmnbp5KxTWY_SnXp6jsqM=\/168x136\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg"}],
'proj_id': 0,
'popularity': 1,
'province': "Testprovince",
}
```

Since I dont know how to extract data from this and the property information doesn't follow the format of a python dictionary I'm stuck. Is it possible to scrape data found inside the script tag?

Current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'nl-BE,nl-NL;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36 RuxitSynthetic/1.0 v17107778776 t3603465970957983448 athfa3c3975 altpub cvcv=2 smf=0'
}

url = 'https://www.randomsite.com'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# Get the correct script tag from html
data = soup.find_all('script')[-3]
```

Comment: You will likely need to do some complex regex. Do those values not appear anywhere else in the html?  Using xpath to extract values from html tags would probably be easier.

Answer (score 0):

As in other cases involving extraction of data from `<script>` elements, you can do that, with lots of string manipulation techniques. Very convoluted, but works, at least in this case:

```
property = {}

#this is where most of the manipulation takes place
dict_str = data.text.replace(""",
        sellerType: """,'xxx,sellerType:').split('xxx')[0].replace("$('body'),",'yyy').split('yyy')[1].strip().split('property: {')[1].split(' }')[0]

#one more - note that [:-1] is necessary here to exclude an empty segment
for pair in dict_str.split(',\n')[:-1]:  
    
    #important - in this case partition() is used instead of split()  
    targ = pair.partition(':')
    property[targ[0].strip()]=targ[2].strip()

#to show it works:
for k,v in property.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Output:

```
code 'A7589'
subtype 'Duplex'
type 'Appartement'
price 285000.00
mainImg 'https://files.test.com/IMG_7674.jpeg'
images [{"z-detail":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/n5H1aP91sXITLfFDWsVN_Er6mOg=\/500x380\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","z-detail-large":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/z76D59FEYt1QYtSBlUX7867FwlE=\/fit-in\/1200x1200\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","z-result":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/TgubrXW2Mv22UWOe4d67vUWVAwA=\/828x618\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","z-result-310":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/7K4ZKsGVKBTrbrel3FEUehkvcdA=\/310x231\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg","tickers":"https:\/\/files.test.com\/hZrwfjBmnbp5KxTWY_SnXp6jsqM=\/168x136\/filters:image-format(pjpg)\/5d\/85\/2390-8532-4531-8768-0b295f761dce\/IMG_7674.jpeg"}]
proj_id 0
popularity 1
province "Testprovince"
```